# mysqli_stmt::bind_param and mysqli_stmt::prepare

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok so i want to do a prepared insert such as:

```
prepare("INSERT INTO `analyzeditemsdetails` SET 
                                     analyzeditem_id = ? ,
                                     start_time = ? ,
                                     end_time = ? 
                                      ");
```

start_time and end_time are stored in the database as sql dates.  Fill in the ?'s in this next statement:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i??',
                           $this->sqlid, 
                           $item['start_time'], 
                           $item['end_time'] 
                           );
```

So basically what do I put in a bind_param method call for sql dates???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be s (string).

```
$stmt->bind_param('iss',
                           $this->sqlid, 
                           $item['start_time'], 
                           $item['end_time'] 
                           );
```